# Embedding lookup from a specific axis

Tags: python, tensorflow

I have two tensors.

```
v, shape=(50, 64, 128), dtype=float32
m, shape=(64, 50, 1), dtype=int32
```

Values in m are integers between 0 and 50 (<=49)
I want to use values of m, to get a specific tensor of v for the same index out of 64. 
Resulting tensor is `r: shape=(64, 50, 128), dtype=float32`

For example values for `r(i, j, 0-128) = v(m(i, j), i, 0-128)`

The closest thing I see is tf.nn.embedding_lookup but I'm not sure how to use it for this use case

Comment: Have you checked  ['tf.gather_nd(..)'](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/gather_nd)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following `tf.nn.embedding_lookup` or `tf.gather_nd` methods to achieve your goals.

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

m_np = np.random.randint(0,50,(64, 50, 1))
m = tf.constant(m_np)
n = tf.random.normal((50, 64, 128))

# Method 1
tmp = tf.nn.embedding_lookup(n,m[:,:,0]) # shape=(64,50,64,128)
tmp = tf.transpose(tmp,[1,3,0,2]) # shape=(50,128,64,64)
result1 = tf.transpose(tf.matrix_diag_part(tmp),[2,0,1]) # shape=(64,50,128)

# Method 2
indices = tf.tile(tf.reshape(tf.range(64),(-1,1,1)),(1,50,1)) # shape=(64,50,1)
indices = tf.concat([m,indices],axis=-1) # shape=(64,50,2)
result2 = tf.gather_nd(n,indices) # shape=(64,50,128)

with tf.Session() as sess:
    # Randomly select a location for test
    n_value,result_value = sess.run([n,result1])
    print((n_value[m_np[5,4],5,:]==result_value[5,4]).all())

# True
```

Comment: Do you know which one will be faster?

Comment: @Milad The second method.